# trs inside a box

Tags: css

Is there a way to put 3 trs ina table inside a box kind of border??

Comment: The ugly way would be to put a border-top on the top one, border-bottom on the third one, and left/right borders on all of them. Not posting this as an answer though because it's incredibly ugly. Looking forward to reading if there's any better suggestions!!

Comment: Actually i want specific 3 tr of my table to be inside a border

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add another `<tbody>` for these `<tr>`s, which seems to do what you mean (note that I couldn't get it to work on IE6).

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>before</td></tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody class="RedBorder">
        <tr><td>1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>2</td></tr>
        <tr><td>3</td></tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>after</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/kobi/gaQ9V/